# Why Is pyinstaller replacing my file directory?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

edit: How To Use --add-data with an entire folder?

Im converting my .py file to .exe using pyinstaller. but when i run it, it gives me this error:

> Failed To Execute Script "test.py" due to unhandled exception: Couldn't open "C:\Users\Dani\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI11962\button_start.png" no such file or directory

> Failed To Obtain/Convert Traceback!

Therefore My Converted Python File (exe) Was in the same directory As My Image.
My path code is built like this:

```
from locate import this_dir
path = this_dir()
str(path) + "\\button_start.png"
```

Comment: Does Hardcoding the path works? Please share more detail of your problem

Comment: what is hardcoding at first place?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use pyinstaller's `--add-data` argument as shown [in the documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-add-data). You can either append this to your command when building the `.exe` or include that in a `pyinstaller.spec` file.

Additional information:
When you execute a `.exe`, that was created with pyinstaller, it will create a temporary folder that is named `_MEI<some numbers>`, just as you showed above. In there, it expects all the necessary files. Therefor, this is also the place, where it will search for the image, no matter where you put your `.exe` to or where you execute it. Since this folder is generated temporarily every time you start the `.exe`, it would not help to simply copy your image there.

Comment: That's Great And All But, How Do I Use It WIth An Entire Directory? (In My Case, The Entire Folder Of The Program, example: Folder With Another Directory And Python File)

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question right, but if you are using `pyinstaller.spec` you can do something like `datas=[str(item) for item in list(Path().absolute().rglob("*"))]` where you would have to insert your path as argument to `Path()`.

Comment: I Don't Understand, Is There A Way To Explain More Clearly?